# Manipulate any embedded iframes

Tags: iframe

I have been creating a website where I would like to embed various iframes. The problem is that I would like to autoplay or mute specific videos, but the apis are very basic of these iframes.

Is there any way to manipulate any iframes (maybe with some js libraries?)

- I have tried accessing contentWindow or get a specific element of the iframe - wont work as its blocking
- I even tried to add simulated mouse click - worked on any elements I targeted at, but when it clicked on the iframe, the videos wont play.

Is there a way with js to simulate real mouse click on the actual iframe or its components?

Edited:

In short, i dont have access to any iframes, thus they are blocking me when i try to get the elements inside them. I need somehow to mute either the audio coming from the iframes or the entire website so the user will not hear the audio from the iframe videos.

These iframes dont have any apis like youtube, so i cant modify their controls

Comment: Your query is more appropriate for StackOverlow.  It also needs more detail for someone to answer the question, like when do you want to autoplay vs mute?  If you're looking to do this when the user opens your page, you can trigger a JS line for the onLoad event.

Comment: Do you control the content of these iframes, or are they third-party iframes?

Comment: They are all third party iframes and they will block if i try to access them using get elements. I have tried simulated clicks etc. The iframes are very basic and they dont have any apis so i cant mute like youtube ones. I fact i cant mute them at all. Unless of course i start the video and then adjust the bolume. Thats what i would like to find out if there is a way to somehow at least to mute the entire page as well

Comment: Due to the [Same Origin](https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication) policy you cannot interact with the content inside of iframes from different sites/domains. You could try to mute the volume of the iframe in the parent page with something like [HTMLIFrameElement.mute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Chrome/API/Browser_API/mute), but that may only work with certain browsers, so check for compatibility before implementing.

Comment: Yeah I could not make it work at all. Its weird how there is no way to mute your website page entirely.